# How to add LUIS intent in bot framework locally?

Tags: node.js, botframework, azure-language-understanding

I am developing a chatbot using bot framework. I have already developed a basic Node Echo Bot and also basic QnA Bot. I am currently developing a LUIS bot of which i already created an intents on [luis.ai](https://www.luis.ai). I have created the bot on Azure and downloaded the source code. Now, my instructor asked me to develop a bot that works with the LUIS app. How can I do this?

Comment: I've edited your question as I understand it. Can you clarify, though: are you just trying to make a bot that interacts with your LUIS app on luis.ai? Or are you trying to create a LUIS bot where the LUIS app runs locally, like [in a container](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/luis/luis-container-howto)?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure that I understand [your unedited question](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/735773f3-a988-40d2-9454-6ddf151724ed/view-source), so I will answer it for both of the two ways that I interpret it.

## Add LUIS to a Bot

See the [Core Bot Sample](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/samples/javascript_nodejs/13.core-bot) for reference.

1. [Add your LUIS connection information to your `.env` file](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/master/samples/javascript_nodejs/13.core-bot/.env)

```sh
MicrosoftAppId=
MicrosoftAppPassword=
LuisAppId=<AddMe>
LuisAPIKey=<AddMe>
LuisAPIHostName=<AddMe>
```

2. [Instantiate a LuisRecognizer](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/master/samples/javascript_nodejs/13.core-bot/dialogs/luisHelper.js#L16)

```
const recognizer = new LuisRecognizer({
    applicationId: process.env.LuisAppId,
    endpointKey: process.env.LuisAPIKey,
    endpoint: `https://${ process.env.LuisAPIHostName }`
}, {}, true);
```

3. [Get the result and intent of user input](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/master/samples/javascript_nodejs/13.core-bot/dialogs/luisHelper.js#L22)

```
const recognizerResult = await recognizer.recognize(context);

const intent = LuisRecognizer.topIntent(recognizerResult);
```

Note: Core Bot does all of this in [luisHelper.js](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/master/samples/javascript_nodejs/13.core-bot/dialogs/luisHelper.js). It then calls it with something like [`bookingDetails = await LuisHelper.executeLuisQuery(this.logger, stepContext.context);`](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/master/samples/javascript_nodejs/13.core-bot/dialogs/mainDialog.js). You can do this, too. An alternative method, if you want to get the intent of every user message, is to include steps 2 and 3 (`recognizer`, `recognizerResult`, `intent`) in [`onMessage()`](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/master/samples/javascript_nodejs/13.core-bot/bots/dialogBot.js#L30), instead.

Additional Note: If you want to start with LUIS from a pre-built sample, the following samples use LUIS:

- [Core Bot](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/samples/javascript_nodejs/13.core-bot)
- [NLP with Dispatch](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/samples/javascript_nodejs/14.nlp-with-dispatch)
- [Virtual Assistant](https://github.com/microsoft/botframework-solutions/blob/master/docs/readme.md#overview)

## Run LUIS Locally

Follow the [LUIS Container How-To](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/luis/luis-container-howto) to run LUIS out of a Docker Container.

[image]

Basically, instead of querying your app on `luis.ai`, you set your bot up to query your docker container, which is running an exported, containerized version of your LUIS app. If you need to improve the app's prediction accuracy after your bot's been running awhile, you re-upload the query logs from your container back to LUIS.

It's a pretty difficult and extensive tutorial, so there's no point in me posting it here. If you run into trouble, feel free to open a new Stack Overflow ticket.